# How do I call a js plugin from within a directives link method - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to wrap Bootstrap 3's modal in a Angular directive.  I get into the link function, but I am not able to call the Bootstrap `.modal()` function.  Here is my html:

```
<h1>This is a test!!!</h1>
<button ng-click="test()">This is a button</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" bsmodal>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And here is my directive:

```
App.directive('bsmodal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.modal('show');
    }
  };
});
```

When I get to the `element.modal('show')`, I get the error,`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'modal'`.  The `element` object looks like a `jQuery` wrapped object, but it still does not have the method.  The part I don't understand is I can call `$('myModal').modal()` in the link function and everything works like it is supposed to work.

So my questions are

1. What is the difference between an `element` and a `jQuery` wrapped object?  (They look the same)
2. How do I call the `modal()` function on the `element` inside the link function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses a reduced version of `jQuery`, `jqLite` which [supports a subset of the functions offered by jQuery](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

It looks like you are loading jQuery anyway in your page. If you load it **before** angular, angular will use it instead of using `jqLite` and you should be able to call `element.modal('show')`.

Comment: I understand it offers a subset of the functions offered by `jQuery`, so I guess that means that it doesn't have the same plugin structure as `jQuery`?

Comment: @jhamm Plugins which attach themselves to `jQuery` object will not be accessible if you are using `jqLite`, yes. However, if `jquery` is loaded before _angular_, there should be no difference between `$('myModal')` and `element`. Try it and see if that works.